# Let $p(z) = z^6 + 9 z^4 + z^3 + 2z + 4$ show that the two zeros of $p(z)$ lying outside the unit circle satisfy $\{ |z \pm 3i| < 1/10$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z) = z^6 + 9 z^4 + z^3 + 2z + 4$, I want to show that the two zeros of $p(z)$ lying outside the unit circle satisfy $ |z \pm 3i| < 1/10$.

By the Rouche's theorem, $p(z)$ has four zeros contained in the unit circle. Therefore, the other two zeros must lie outside of the unit circle.

Here is my attempt:
let $f(z) = z^6 + 9z^4$ and $g(z) = z^3 + 2z + 4$.
Now $f(z)$ clearly has two zeros at $z = 3i$ and $z = - 3i$ in the domain $D = \{ |z + 3i| < 1/10\}$.
If I can show the $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ on $\partial D$, then I can apply the Rouche's theorem.
So that $p(z) = z^6 + 9 z^4 + z^3 + 2z + 4$ has same number of zeros with $f(z) = z^6 + 9z^4$ on the domain $D = \{ |z + 3i| < 1/10\}$.
However, seems like I can't prove the inequality $|h(z)| < |f(z)|$ required by the Rouche's theorem.

Can anyone provide me some help please?

Comment: what is $h(z)$?

Comment: Is it your own idea to apply Rouché's theorem or is it an exercise that is given to you ? I ask it because Rouché's theorem is not a universal panacea ...

Comment: @JeanMarie This is an exercise from the section of Rouche's Theorem in Gamelin's Complex analysis textbook ..... So I think Rouche's theorem is a good place to start

Comment: @Raffaele Sorry I made a typo, it should be $g(z)$ instead of $h(z)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|z+3i|=0.1$ then $$|f(z)| =|z|^4 |z-3i ||z+3i| =0.1 |z-3i| |z|^4 \geq 0.1\cdot 5.9 \cdot (2.9)^4 >41$$
and
$$|h(z)|=|z^3 +2z +4|\geq |z|^3 +2|z| +4 =(3,1)^3 +6.2 +4 <40$$
So $$|f(z)|> |h(z)|$$ on $|z+3i|=0.1 $

Comment: Thanks for you solution. For the second equation is it $|h(z)| = |z^3 + 2z + 4| \leq |z|^3 + 2|z| + 4 \leq (3.1)^3 + 2(3.1) + 4$?

Comment: A typo: $|z^3 +2z +4|\color{red}{\leq} |z|^3 +2|z| +4$